# Remove "." and "\" from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

my project is to capture a log number from Google Sheet using gspread module. But now the problem is that the log number captured is in the form of string ".\1300". I only want the number in the string but I could not remove it using the below code.

Tried using .replace() function to replace "\" with "" but failed.

```
a='.\1362'
a.replace('\\',"")
```

Should obtain the string "1362" without the symbol. 
But the result obtained is ".^2"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\136` has special meaning (similar to `\n` for newline, `\t` for tab, etc). Seemingly it represents `^`.

Check out the following example:

```py
a = '.\1362'
a = a.replace('\\',"")
print(a)

b = r'.\1362'
b = b.replace('\\',"")
print(b)
```

Produces

```
.^2
.\1362
```

Now, if your Google Sheets module sends `.\1362` instead of `.\\1362`, if is very likely because you are in fact supposed to receive `.^2`. Or, there's a problem with your character encoding somewhere along the way.

The `r` modifier I put on the `b` variable means *raw string*, meaning Python will not interpret backlashes and leave your string alone. This is only really useful when typing the strings in manually, but you could perhaps try:

```py
a = r'{}'.format(yourStringFromGoogle)
```

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, the original code did in fact discard the result of the .replace() method. I've updated the code, but please note that the string interpolation issue remains the same.

Comment: I need to obtain the integer value for the .\1234 in order to compare with the actual latest build no from a website which is an integer value to proceed with other functions.

Comment: Since strings are immutable doesn't a.replace('\\',"") followed by print(a) just print the original a?

Comment: Haha, oh boy, of course you are right! In this example, however, it doesn't change the outcome. The replace method still runs on an already interpreted string. I'll update my most with correct code. Thank you for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `a='.\1362'`, `a` will only have three bytes:

```
a = '.\1362'`
print(len(a))  # => 3
```

That is because `\132` represents a single character. If you want to create a six byte string with a dot, a slash, and the digits 1362, you either need to escape the backslash, or create a raw string:

```
a = r'.\1362'
print(len(a))  # => 6
```

In either case, calling `replace` on a string **will not replace the characters in that string**. `a` will still be what it was before calling `replace`. Instead, `replace` returns a *new* string:

```
a = r'.\1362'
b = a.replace('\\', '')
print(a)  # => .\1362
print(b)  # => .1362
```

So, if you want to replace characters, calling `replace` is the way to do it, but you've got to save the result in a new variable or overwrite the old.

See [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=backslash#string-and-bytes-literals) in the official python documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your string should contains 2 backslashes like this `.\\1362` or use `r'.\1362'` (which is declaring the string as raw and then it will be converted to normal during compile time). If there is only one backslash, Python will understand that `\136` mean `^` as you can see (ref: [link](https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/letter-e-circumflex-accent-e-circumflex-lowercase-ascii-code-136.html))

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening here is that `\1362` is being encoded as `^2` because of the backslash, so you need to make the string raw before you're able to use it, you can do this by doing

```
a = r'{}'.format(rawInputString)
```

or if you're on python3.6+ you can do

```
a = rf'{rawInputString}'
```